# How can things still work if you even figured the size of data types wrongly?

Tags: gdb, typedef

This is what is in the code:

```
typedef  unsigned long  int  ub4;   /* unsigned 4-byte quantities */
```

However:

```
(gdb) p sizeof(unsigned long  int)
$7 = 8
```

So `unsigned long  int` actually takes 8 bytes for my CPU.How can things still work when there're such fundamental mistakes??

BTW,why `ub4` can't be recognized by gdb??

```
(gdb) p sizeof(ub4)
No symbol "ub4" in current context.
```

Comment: "How do things still work?" "BTW why don't things work?" Wtf.

Comment: What is the conflict?  You've got a comment that's apparently wrong, and a somewhat misnamed variable.  You haven't shown us anything that requires `ub4` to be four bytes.  For your BTW, it may be that typedefs are not present in the debug information, or gdb may just not handle that.  Unless the `typedef` substitution occurs before debug information is amassed in gcc, I see no particular reason why or why not.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume that you're talking about C. Please tag your question with the correct language.

Things can still "work" until the developer has code that *assumes* a `ub4` is precisely 4 bytes. Then, such errors can lead to things like buffer overruns (which may not be obviously detectable, or could even go unnoticed for years before *randomly* manifesting symptoms) ... or they could just happen to not cause symptoms. They're still invoking Undefined Behaviour, though, and should be fixed.

It's also possible that the developer just happened to never really use the type width as an assumption in his code.

Comment: How will you name `ub4` so that it can be meaningful for different architectures while still containing info on byte size??

Comment: @compile-fan: `unsigned long int`

Comment: @compile-fan: (as a serious answer, thinking about this from the other direction, `stdint.h` contains fixed-width types. You can use `uint32_t` and _know_ that it's 32-bits wide.)